# Webpack 5: Loads dynamic json file not from root

Tags: javascript, webpack, dynamic-import, webpack-5

What is wrong with my dynamic import? Why does it add a wrong path?

This line of code worked in Webpack 3, now with 5 it's not working:

```
 loadCuisine() {
   import(`@storage/json/cuisines/listofcuisines_${window.App.locale}.json`)
            .then(this.addCuisines);
 },
```

`@storage` is an alias for: `'@storage': path.join(__dirname, 'storage/app/public'),`

The problem is, that somehow the path of the dynamic JSON is wrong.

The error says:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk storage_app_public_json_cuisines_listofcuisines_en_json failed.
(missing: https://example.com/letscook/js/storage_app_public_json_cuisines_listofcuisines_en_json.65154af945c63aa7e43d.js)
```

If you notice it should be `https://example.com/js/` and not `https://example.com/letscook/js/`.

Even the source map looks correctly:

```
loadCuisine: function loadCuisine() {
      __webpack_require__("./storage/app/public/json/cuisines lazy recursive ^\\.\\/listofcuisines_.*\\.json$")("./listofcuisines_".concat(window.App.locale, ".json")).then(this.addCuisines);
    },
```

Any idea why it puts the subpath? (btw the error happens on the subpage `https://example.com/letscook`)

Edit:

Here is one option set in webpack:

```
output: {
    publicPath: '',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js',
},
```

Comment: Apparently, it's the issue with [publicPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846070/wepback-loading-chunk-failed-after-using-import). However, now I get the issue with workbox: `workbox Network request for 'https://js/app.js' threw an error. TypeError: Failed to fetch`

Comment: The only hack for workbox was to use `modifyURLPrefix: { '/': '', },`